# MySQL How to order by column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL Tables. In this abstract example I will use these to explain my issue:

```
Persons(person_id, name);
Competition(competition_id, first, second, third);
```

`First`, `second` and `third` refer to `person_id` and I want to get the names in this order. If I use

```
SELECT name 
  FROM Persons
     , Competition 
 WHERE person_id = first 
    OR person_id second 
    OR person_id = third;
```

the names are sorted by their table order (usually the same order like sorted by primary key). How can I order them right?

Edit:
I need to enter a competition_id and want to get a table with three name lines in the right order

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need multiple joins:

```
SELECT c.*, p1.name, p2.name, p3.name
FROM Competition c LEFT JOIN
     Persons p1
     ON p1.person_id = c.first LEFT JOIN
     Persons p2
     ON p2.person_id = c.second LEFT JOIN
     Persons p3
     ON p3.person_id = c.third;
```

This puts the names for a given row in `competition` in the same row.  That seems like a sensible thing to do.

EDIT:

If you want the first matching name, you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT c.*, COALESCE(p1.name, p2.name, p3.name)
```

Comment: it seems that OP wants coalesce(p1.name, p2.name, p3.name)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, a seperate table is required.

```
Persons(person_id, name);
Mapper(pk_mapper_id, fk_competition_id, fk_person_id, rang)
Competition(competition_id);
```

Here I can order by rang.